# Letter closing other than "Love"

Tags: word-choice

I am writing an email to a family member (in-law or brother/sister). While in the past I used "love" and signed off with my first name for closing, I usually wondered if there are better words I could use instead of "Love". For one thing, it sounds uncreative and a little trite. For another, it seems phony as I do not feel a close relation to some family members. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

off the top of my head, you could use the old "yours truly" but that is distant and formal. How about "Fondly" or "Best Wishes" and "Have a great day!"

Answer (score 3):

In a personal letter, while there is some traditional etiquette, you can largely close it however you'd like. Any sort of well-wishing or expression of affection/sincerity is acceptable. A few examples:

- "Best Wishes"
- "Yours Truly"
- "See you soon"
- "Wishing you good fortune in the New Year"
- "God bless"

Anything works really.

Answer (score 3):

- "Regards"
- "Best Regards"
- "Best Wishes to Your Family"

(I agree that "Love" is not always the most appropriate closing but as long as it won't be misconstrued, I err on the side of using "Love" because it is not "said" often enough!)

Comment: I agree. Love is not said often enough. However, doesn't it sound a little imposing (or insincere?) if you are not that close to the other side?

Comment: @inewbie, I realize this is entirely based on opinion - but if imposing or not said with sincerity, it's not the best closing - but if it is someone who may be a long-time family member by marriage or someone who is not immediate family but you're close to, (like my sister-in-law or uncle's 3rd wife), I would still say "Love" - ***if*** the communication was of a personal nature.

Answer (score 0):

Fond regards,
Warm regards, or
All the best

Closer relative:
With warmest affection,
With much love, or 
Much love to you, Dad,

Answer (score 0):

> Sincerely, [name]

or

> –[name]

Using an *en [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)* before the name. (It may supposed to be an *em dash*, but w\e IMO, just as long as it isn't a hyphen or a plan old dash.) Personally, I omit the space to denote attribution, to avoid confusing it with any other use.

Another option is to omit the sign-off entirely or phrase it into a TL;DR:

> I hope to see you at [that party I mentioned]. Don't forget to bring your towel!

Also, emotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make a regard to an upcoming holiday such as Christmas, Halloween, The new year, or really any holiday
examples:
Merry Christmas, [name]
Happy New Year, [name]
Have a Spookly-good Halloween, [name]
Love and good wishes this Valentine's, [name]
but really, saying 'love' isn't so bad.
love,
anonymous

Comment: Where in the world is Halloween a holiday?

Comment: @KillingTime Christmas Eve is considered to be a "partial" holiday...whatever that means. It is not much of a stretch to consider "All Hallow's eve" the same for "All Saint's day"...

Comment: @KillingTime Halloween is considered a holiday in the USA, especially for families with children, although not in the sense of school/work closures.  The holiday is connected with the Christian observance of All Saint's Day as well as the pagan festival Samhain.